# How to consider cos(phi) & cos(psi) in my following code to calculate the received optical power for VLC LED system?

Tags: matlab, led

dears. I am trying to implement Matlab's indoor visible light communication system to calculate the optical received power. And I successfully made a line of sight calculation for the power between the source LED and the receiver PD based on the following formula,

[image]

That is in the following line code:

```
H_A1 = (m+1)*Adet.*cosphi_A1.^(m+1)./(2*pi.*D1.^2);   % Channel DC gain for source
```

As shown in the above picture, there is **cos(phi)** and **cos(psi)**, *Tf & Gc* will be ignored. In the following code, **cos(phi)** and **cos(psi)** are ignored and considered **1** due to line of sight rules.

What I am trying here to do is I want to consider **cos(phi)** and **cos(psi)** in the above line of code by assuming **psi = 0 **and** phi = 0:5:30.**

I want to add **cos(phi)** and **cos(psi)** in the following line based on the above picture

```
H_A1 = (m+1)*Adet.*cosphi_A1.^(m+1)./(2*pi.*D1.^2);   % Channel DC gain for source
```

And give **phi=0**, **psi= 0** to **30** with increasing step **5**.

In every new value to **psi**, I want to calculate **H_A1** in order to calculate the received power **P_rec**.

Any assistance, please?

Matlab code:

```
close all;
clear all;
clc;

%% LED/PD Parameters

theta = 70;                       % Semi-angle at half power
m = -log10(2)/log10(cosd(theta)); % Lambertian order of emission
P_total = 20;                     % Transmitted optical power by individual LED
Adet = 1e-4;                      % Detector physical area of a PD

%% Optical elements parameters

Ts = 1;                           % Gain of an optical filter; ignore if no filter is used
index = 1.5;                      % Refractive index of a lens at a PD; ignore if no lens is used
FOV = 60*pi/180;                  % FOV of a receiver
G_Con = (index^2)/sin(FOV);       % Gain of an optical concentrator; ignore if no lens is used

%% Room parameters
             
lx = 5; ly = 5; lz = 3;         % Room dimensions in meter
h = 2.15;                       % The distance between the source and receiver plane

%% Mesh setup
% 2 dimensional setup

XT = 0; YT = 0;                   % The Position of the LED
Nx = lx*10; Ny = ly*10;           % Number of grids in the receiver plane
x = -lx/2 : lx/Nx : lx/2;
y = -ly/2 : ly/Ny : ly/2;
[XR, YR] = meshgrid(x,y);         % Receiver plane grid

%% Computation based on LOS channel equations

D1 = sqrt((XR-XT(1,1)).^2 + (YR-YT(1,1)).^2 + h^2);   % Distance vector from source
cosphi_A1 = h./D1;                                    % Angle vector
H_A1 = (m+1)*Adet.*cosphi_A1.^(m+1)./(2*pi.*D1.^2);   % Channel DC gain for source
P_rec = P_total.*H_A1.*Ts.*G_Con;                     % Received power from source  
P_rec_dB = 10*log10(P_rec); 
    
%% Plotting

meshc(x,y,P_rec_dBm);
colorbar
xlabel('X (m)');
ylabel('Y (m)');
zlabel('Received power (dBm)');
axis([-lx/2 lx/2 -ly/2 ly/2 min(min(P_rec_dBm)) max(max(P_rec_dBm))]);
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could edit your question to identify what result (or error) you get from your code and how that differs from what you expect

Comment: @JimQuirk Thank you very much for your feedback, I added new information.

Answer (score 1):

You can define phi as a vector, but there will be problems with the plot meshgrid because of **dimension mismatch**
indeed for each angle, there will be a **unique graph** and we can't plot a graph for all values of angles given in a vector.
Psi is also affected by this.

it is possible that we have received power as a vector because cos will be a vector in the formula, but it is not possible to plot the meshgrid for this vector, each received power value has a unique meshgrid graph.

Comment: @RohitGupta: I read this to suggest that what the OP is asking for isn't possible for the reasons stated. If I'm reading that correctly, then this is an answer. I don't know if it's a _correct_ solution, but it looks like a sincere attempt to answer.